# How can I improve my system performance?? As it is working very slow

Tags: apt, dpkg, performance, settings

I have Dell Inspiron N4050 i5 2gb.
Am running dual boot (Ubuntu 14.04 along with Win7).
As I am a new user (more specifically learner).

In Ubuntu am facing several issue regarding the performance. Response time for any operation is very high. And during browsing whenever am watching any video it's always getting hanged. Please help regarding system performance.

I am not able to install many of the software and updates, it's giving following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1    
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @markkirby- sorry i didn't mean to be rude...it's just i thought that system performance and that error msg may be 2 different issues.

Comment: Its OK I have seen your replies to my comments now, I was just not notified of them for some reason, so I retract my previous comment but I think both issues are related due to same error but we will see

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster- am facing poor system performance. Very slow response and getting hanged frequently.

Comment: Do you have your gpu drivers installed?

Comment: @Paludan - am new user so i dont know how to check that

Comment: @Sumit post the ouput of "lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12" in pastebin

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `s` in your `/etc/default/grub`. Remove the `s` and save the file. After that run this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic   Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic

Comment: whats the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`?

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""